# Automation screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I'm currently working on an automation project, I've created this simple program to report testing information and to take screenshots.

```
package ReportTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import ReportTest.Utitlity;
public class ReportTest {


ExtentReports report;
ExtentTest logger;
WebDriver driver;


@Test
public void verifyBlogTitle()
{

    report =new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\reganc3\\desktop\\report\\LearnAutomation.html");


    logger=report.startTest("VerifyBlogTitle");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Browser started");

    driver.get("http://www.learn-automation.com");

    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Application is up and running");

    String title = driver.getTitle();

    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Selenium"));

    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Title Verified");
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result)
{
    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {

    String screenshot_path = Utitlity.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
    logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "TitleVerification", screenshot_path);

    }

    report.endTest(logger);
    report.flush();

    driver.get("C:\\Users\\reganc3\\desktop\\report\\LearnAutomation.html");
}
}
```

Here is my Utilitys class which is being called to take the screenshot

```
package ReportTest;



import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import java.util.*;

public class Utitlity {



public static String captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName)
{
    try
    {
        TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;

        File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String dest = " C:\\Users\\reganc3\\desktop\\ " +screenshotName+ ".png";

        File destination=new File(dest);

        FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);

        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");

        return dest;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
    }

}
 }
```

I am getting the following error

**Exception while taking screenshot null

I'm quite new to Selenium and TestNG so I'm basically looking for someone to shed some light on this and give me some pointers in the right direction and to understand what is actually happening with my code that's throwing this error.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: are you sure the path that you have provided inside the captureScreenshot is valid

Comment: Hi @rajNishKuMar is it this line you mean " String dest = " C:\\Users\\reganc3\\desktop\\ " +screenshotName+ ".png"; " I pressumed that line of code just pointed to where the screenshot will be saved once it has been created?

Comment: also to help you there is great video how to work with extent reports https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBj7pxhZXhY

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Thank you. I have actually used that video to get the code I have now and my code is the same

Comment: ok great then just confirm me that the path that u r using in your code to save screen shot is real i.e exist on your pc

Comment: Yes it is thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110257/discussion-between-colin-and-raj-n-ish-ku-m-ar).

Comment: There are spaces in your destination path. I think that it's not a problem in the middle of the path, but it won't find your directory with a space at the beginning. Try removing the space.

Comment: Hi @NicolasG.Duvivier I got rid of spaces, still same error. Thanks though.

Comment: make some wait after drivr.get(), print screenshotName and check what it print. seems ur problem is in ur dest.

Comment: hummm... why are you using backslashes ? EDIT : Nevermind, it normalizes the path anyway.

Comment: Can you Debug to identify the line that generates the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong version of ExtentReport for the code I had.

The code I was using was for a newer up to date version of ExtentReport and the maven dependency I had was pointing to an older version. The code itself worked perfectly when I updated the dependency to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this method to take screenshots in my tests:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

 public void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String methodName) {
        File screenshotFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile,new
 File("Screenshots\\"+methodName+" "+GetTimeStampValue()+".png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

and this method to get a TimeStamp:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public  String GetTimeStampValue()throws IOException{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       
    Date time=cal.getTime();
    String timestamp=time.toString();
    String systime=timestamp.replace(":", "-");
    return systime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
```